# Как создать файл ресурсов в Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift

Возможно ли в Xcode создать файл ресурсов?

Для вот такой ситуации, допустим у меня есть 4 view controller -а и на каждом есть кнопка "Ok" и вот теперь мне нужно чтоб на кнопках было написано не "Ok" , а "Next".

Мне нужно открыть каждую кнопку и поменять текст.

Можно ли создать файл строковых ресурсов и просто указывать ссылки на нужный ресурс?

Или как это работает в Xcode?

Comment: Ты хочешь делать это прям в Storyboard/Xib или в коде?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov Не знаю, мне кажется удобно из `Storyboard`?

Answer (score 1):

В итоге нашел подробную статью как это сделать через `plist` файл

1. Создать `plist` файл. Я указал имя Localizable
2. В инспекторе этого файла нажать кнопку `Localize`
3. Добавить пары ключ значение как на скрине

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Потом добавить вот такой код в проект

   import Foundation

   private class Localizator {

   static let sharedInstance = Localizator()

   lazy var localizableDictionary: NSDictionary! = {
       if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Localizable", ofType: "plist") {
           return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
       }
       fatalError("Localizable file NOT found")
   }()

   func localize(string: String) -> String {
       guard let localizedString = localizableDictionary.valueForKey(string)?.valueForKey("value") as? String else {
           assertionFailure("Missing translation for: (string)")
           return ""
       }
       return localizedString
   }
   }

   extension String {
   var localized: String {
       return Localizator.sharedInstance.localize(self)
   }
   }
5. и вот так можно получить доступ

   print(“Accept”.localized)

И в логе получите то значение которое находиться по ключу "Accept" , в этом случае это будет строка "Accept". Так как название ключа и значение совпадают

И вот  ссылка на статью оригинал

https://medium.com/@dcordero/a-different-way-to-deal-with-localized-strings-in-swift-3ea0da4cd143#.7hnfq2yeu

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе необходимо изменить только строки, которые показываются в кнопках или лейблах, то я вижу два решения:

- При необходимости поменять текст можно просто с помощью Xcode поменять все строки с помощью поиска и замены;
- Второй способ более правильный - использовать `NSLocalizedString` и хранить все строки в файле локализации. Это позволит быстро менять текст и легко добавлять новые локализации. Пример использования:

  ```
  let button = UIButton()
  button.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("button_titles.ok", comment: ""), for: .normal)
  ```

  А так будет выглядеть `Localizable.strings`:

  ```
  "button_titles.ok" = "OK";
  ```

Comment: Это из Objective C?

Comment: В Swift тоже можно использовать

Comment: Но я так понял, что таким образом можно устанавливать из кода?

Comment: Я всегда локализацию делаю в коде, но также есть возможность добавить локализации для Storyboard и Xib. Второй способ не очень удобный, потому что возникают сложности с передачей текста для локализации переводчику или с использованием стороннего сервиса.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то ты присваиваешь title кнопкам из кода? У меня просто нет опыта поэтому мне не совсем понятно ты в ответе говоришь что второй способ правильнее, потом в комментах, что второй способ не очень удобный... Так если я правильно понял, то с помощью `NSLocalizedString` я могу внести все String которые мне нужно и потом по ключу их использовать?

Comment: Я мел в виду локализацию через Storyboard. А с использованием `Localizable.strings` все хорошо. Я добавил пример в ответ.